# How to convert GenericData to JsonNode

Tags: java, spring-kafka

Stacked in next task:
when I consume new Kafka Avro message

```
@KafkaListener(topics = "#{'${kafka.topic.name}'}",
        properties = {"specific.avro.reader=false"})
public void consume(ConsumerRecord<String, GenericData> record)
```

I need to get JsonNode from message value

```
try {
        JsonNode recordNode = mapper.readTree(record.value().toString());
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Failed to parse consumer record " + key, ex);
        }
```

and here I get `java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.avro.generic.GenericData$Record cannot be cast to org.apache.avro.generic.GenericData`
what's wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error suggests, its not the GenericData you get there in ConsumerRecord but the GenericData.Record. Did you try with?

```
    public void consume(ConsumerRecord<String, GenericData.Record> record)
```

or

```
    public void consume(ConsumerRecord<String, GenericRecord> record)
```